# How does React know this.props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

When I watch tutorials they try to read `this.props` without defining the term `props` anywhere. Is props a keyword? If not how does React know that it is props without defining it anywhere in the code?

Comment: That's why you `extends React.Component`, so you _inherit_ things like the props property getting set: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 2):

No, `props` isn't a keyword. The `React.Component` constructor receives the props object (because `React.createElement` passes them to the component function as the first argument; JSX generates the calls to `React.createElement`) and assigns `props` to the instance being created, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
//          ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−− parameter
    this.props = props;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− assignment
    // ...
}
```

That's why if you create your own constructor, you **have** to pass the object you receive as the first parameter to `super` like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
//           ^^^^^^−−−−−−−−− passing them on to `super`
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But we can write ```this.props``` with out the constructor. My question is can we say ```this.x``` or any variable (```this.anyvariable```)to access the props?

Comment: @David - In JavaScript, if a subclass doesn't have a declared constructor, the JavaScript engine generates one that looks like this: `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`. So if your component class doesn't have a declared constructor, that one is used, which passes on `props` to `React.Component`, which assigns it to `this`. *"My question is can we say this.x or any variable (this.anyvariable)to access the props?"* With respect, that isn't what your question asked. :-) But the answer to *that* question is: No. You have to use the `props` object. To get the `x` prop, it's `this.props.x`.

Comment: With respect my question was like that. Since I am not native for english it might have different sense. Thanks you answered me briefly!